# How to differentiate access to data at the database server level?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In DB i have three roles: guest, client and admin.
In my django project, there are three connections under these roles

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'guest',
        'PASSWORD': 'guest',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
    'admin': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    },
    'customer': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'customer',
        'PASSWORD': 'customer',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

How and where can I change the connection to the database depending on whether the user is authenticated or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that you are using psycopg2 to connect to the Postgresql RDBMS. What I would do is specify what Postgresql user you want to use before you execute your query.

For example:

```
import psycopg2
        
def func1():
    
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "exampledb", user = "user1", password = "user1password", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name;")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)

def func2():

    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "exampledb", user = "user2", password = "user2password", host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name (col1, col2) VALUES(1, 2);")
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

I would also be very careful with the admin user, from a security standpoint I would not allow this account to be used for the server-side scripting, this is because if and sql injection is executed, then a lot of harm could be caused. For prevention of sql injections in python I would recommend this: https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/